# How to create a Vec with data type ExprOrSpread for an SWC plugin?

Tags: rust, swc-compiler

I am developing an SWC plugin in Rust.

```ini
[dependencies]
swc_core = "0.75.*"
swc_ecma_parser = "0.133.8"
```

I need to replace the argument in `console.log("hello")` with `console.log("world")`

```rust
fn visit_mut_call_expr(&mut self, n: &mut CallExpr) {
    n.args = "new argument";
}
```

`n.args` accepts a `Vec` vector with data type `ExprOrSpread`.

I don't understand what `ExprOrSpread` is. Any value returns an error.

It works like this:

```rust
fn visit_mut_call_expr(&mut self, n: &mut CallExpr) {
    let mut vector: Vec<ExprOrSpread> = vec![];
    n.args = vector;
}
```

I replace `console.log("hello")` with `console.log()`.

How do I insert the string "world"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, you're interested in traits such as [`From<Expr>`](https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_core/ecma/utils/swc_ecma_ast/struct.ExprOrSpread.html#impl-From%3CExpr%3E-for-ExprOrSpread), which allow you to transform things into each other. And builders or [factories](https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_core/ecma/utils/trait.ExprFactory.html) to create a new one.

```rust
use swc_ecma_ast::*;
use swc_ecma_utils::ExprFactory;

fn visit_mut_call_expr(&mut self, n: &mut CallExpr) {
    let first = Lit::Str("world".into());
    n.args = vec![first.as_arg()];
}
```